# Change text in WPF window

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a WPF window without any tasks or delegation.

I simply build a small window, that says something like:

> Update in progress, please wait...

and begin copying some files.

At the end it shall say:

> Update done, have a nice day.

At the beginning the text is different, depending on some initial factors. Everything works fine, except the change of the text.

As a reminder: I have NO tasks or the like. Everything is done like in a good old structured programming technique.

But when I do something like:

```
CopyText.Text = "Please wait, files will be copied!";
```

I get no changes. Even when I write it like this:

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate
{
    CopyText.Text = "Please wait, files will be copied!";
});
```

I get no changes in the window. Somehow I think I'm wrong here.

Does someone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: You are more likely falling into a popular trap: doing all the job inside a single loop (`while` ?). This means, what text will not get updated, until you finish your job and only then UI has chance to *repaint*. Solution is simple: put job into another thread (`Thread`/`Task`/`BackgroundWorker`) or split job into parts and use `Timer`.

Comment: `Everything is done like in a good old structured programming technique.`

but no MVVM? Look up Data Binding and MVVM

Comment: are you copying the files on UI thread (and blocking it)?

Comment: `good old structured programming technique` does not allow updating of UI thread while it is working on other things. Why? Because it needs to finish its job before`redrawing` the view. Since view cannot be refreshed, you will see `good old` not responding scene.

Comment: *Does someone have an idea what I could be doing wrong?* Yes, you're trying to use WPF as if it were WinForms or another *good old structured programming* language... but it's not. Learn how to use it properly.

Comment: I used a thread() and now everything works fine. from there i can use my dispatcher.invoke's ;)